# View json parse object structure in eclipse javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to view the json parse objects structure in eclipse. Due to the cross domain issue I am unable to use the console.log() to view the structure in chrome. How else can I view this [object Object] returned structure from Json.Parse ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`JSON.stringify(object)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), it will convert your object to a string(then you can alert, write or whatever you want).

**EDIT**

If this is the returned value from the request:

```
'{"Date":"05\/25\/2013","Description":"New2","Details":"New2","Item‌​RequestedID":"1343","Picture":,255,217],"Status":1,"User":"2120","Use‌​rName":"Ind1"}'
```

It is not yet parsed, so you need to use [`JSON.parse(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse it to a valid JS Object. Once it is parsed, this will be the structure of your object:

```
{
    "Date": "05\/25\/2013",
    "Description": "New2",
    "Details": "New2",
    "Item‌​RequestedID": "1343",
    "Picture": ,
    255,
    217], "Status": 1,
"User": "2120",
"Use‌​rName": "Ind1"
}
var obj = JSON.parse(result)//where result is the string above and obj is the parsed object with this structure
```

Then you will be able to access what you need doing `obj.Date`, `obj.Description` etc

Comment: Don't post code inside comments, especially formatted JSON. Please update your question with those code, format it with jsbeautifier.org

Comment: Ok, thanks will do. How can I consume this object in javascript ?

Comment: What do you mean with "consume"? Destroy? Or parse?

Comment: Anyway it seems that the returned value isn't yet parsed, so you have to use JSON.parse(string) to return a JS object!

Comment: get the value of Key Description and all other values.

Comment: How do I get the values of Description and all other fields ?
jsbeautifier.org does not do much on the json result

Comment: The object is returned with Json.Parse(data) if I do an alert(data) I get a [object Object] returned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30657/discussion-between-lightstyle-and-krivahn-doss)

Comment: You right. Had the json.parse after the stringify. It now shows {"Date":"05/25/2013,"Description":"New2", etc. How do I get the Description info ? Data[0].Description ?

Comment: Please join the chat. It is better to avoid extended discussion in comments!

Comment: Thanks its working. Not sure why json.Parse formated it differently. I use to access it data[0].Description. After I added a field I must access it data.Description. Thanks again much appreciated.

Comment: Well, I'm happy it works. I had pointed out what the problem was, I just needed to tell you ;)